# MySQL REGEX using SUBSTRING with uknown length?

Tags: mysql, regex

Say I have this data:

```
First line of text etc etc
Second line of text here
```

*I want to return the first line, and I know how it starts, but not how it ends, only that it ends with a line break.* This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(`file`, LOCATE('First line', `file`), LOCATE('First line', `file`)+10)
FROM `test`
```

This works except `+10` won't always be +10. The only marker I have to know where to stop is a new line, but I don't think it's possible to use regex in SUBSTRING. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you want to retrive the word 'first line' or the firt line itself?

Comment: @JoeGJoseph The first line itself. Your answer below isn't right.

Comment: I have updated my answer.. plz check now

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT 
      SUBSTRING( `file`, LOCATE('First line', `file`),
          LOCATE("\n",`file`) 
 FROM `test`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`file`, 1, LOCATE("\n", `file`) - 1) FROM `test`;
```

Substring starts from one, not zero.  Subtracting one from the result of LOCATE excludes the line return.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to return a line that starts with a specific value;
So I can suggest a query like this:

```sql
set @startOfLine = 'First line';

select 
  substring(`file`, 
            locate(@startOfLine, `file`),
            locate('\n', substring(concat(`file`, '\n'), locate(@startOfLine, `file`)))
  ) line
from `test`;
```

<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc39a2e/4)</kbd>

I add a `\n` character at the end of `file` so you can get the last line also.